# How to identify missing values/duplicate values in excel?

Tags: excel, merge

I have four columns of data (day and time A; precipitation amount; day and time B; temperature) the two day and time columns (A and C) should match up (i.e. 16:00 12/10/19 in both columns). However, column A and C have duplicates which are not consistent (e.g. two 16:00 in column A but only one in column C) and I need to retain the duplicates as they contain variations in precipitation or temperature (e.g. A has two reads for precipitation that are biologically important but B does not).

Is there any way I can merge these four columns together by:

-(a) linking A with precipitation amount and C with temperature; and

-(b) without deleting the duplicates but instead placing spaces in either columns where there is space?

Here is my data - red represents duplicates (a tiny subset - I have 365 days and four years of data):

[image: current data]

This is what I'd like it to look like (so there is a gap in second column where there isn't a duplicate):

[image: what I would like]

Thank you very very much for any help!! :)

Comment: Are the duplicates only in the precitation datecolumn or are there duplicates in the temperature dates as well? Will the duplicate dates have different precipitation values that you need to retain? If the numbers are the same for duplicated dates, it would be way easier to just click the ribbon command to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the duplicate dates are **only in column A,** then you can recreate the dates and temp values in a helper column. In column E, start in row 2 to pull only the unique dates.

```
=IF(A5=A4,"",A5)
```

Copy down. Then in cell F2, use a lookup formula to pull the matching temperature

```
=XLOOKUP(E5,C:C,D:D,"")
```

Or, if you don't have Office 365 with the new Xlookup, use Vlookup

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(E5),VLOOKUP(E5,C:D,2,FALSE),"")
```

Copy down.

You can then copy the result and use Paste Special > Values to overwrite the original data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In C2, add this formula, and then fill it down:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",A2)
```

This says if date in the row above it is the same, then return a blank. Otherwise, return the date.

Comment: that does't really insert a cell, does it?